# How to handle good questions which cannot be answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've seen some questions which are clear and well written and described asking how to do something which is technically not possible. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952901/how-to-get-the-shell-folder-icon-location-for-a-specific-folder#comment46160793_28952901) is asking how to obtain the file path of where to load a folder icon the same way that Windows Explorer does. Technically however there is no answer to this question, as written as so, because these icons can be generated on-the-fly by Windows, so there is no file.

The user could edit the question in that case, but that would change the scope of the question. User could also delete the question and ask a different one, but that's up to the user to do.

What can I do to make Stack Overflow know this question cannot be answered in its current form? None of the close options are anywhere close to this scenario, and I'd sure hate to down-vote it.

Comment: We could put these questions into ice until the time they become *technically possible* to answer. It still *may* work for Walt Disney, after all.

Comment: In this case in particular, I doubt there will ever be an answer, unless Windows decides to go backwards in development.

Comment: I don't know. Have they put the Start menu back yet? ;)

Comment: Windows 10 has a combination of the old and new menu together...

Comment: *Proving* that something is impossible is a wholeheckofalot of work, a maintenance headache and never appreciated by SO users.  I used to post answers like that for a while but got feddup with the downvote magnet problem.  The practical approach is that when a question doesn't have an answer then it isn't possible :)

Comment: @Hans In this case it's a no brainer... Thinking of the Matrix... "There is no file."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> That's not technically possible due *reasons*.

That's it. Answering a question saying that "you can't do it" **explaining why** they can't, is an answer, not the one that OP wants but it answers the question, no?

Comment: Wow, I think we literally tied at answering this :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You beat Braiam by 2 seconds...

Comment: You got it backwards, @Jerry :/

Comment: Braiam has `2015-3-9 23:56:16Z` while Bradley has `2015-3-9 23:56:18Z` Yeah you're right.

Answer (score 4):

Answer it!

"You can't" is a perfectly valid answer, provided you have the evidence (and preferably documentation with links) to back it up. There are plenty of *great* "You can't" answers out there.